# Array of folder names without space in bash

Tags: bash, glob

I'm trying to run through a list of folders that have a space in them. The folders look something like

```
/Volumes/SAMPLE
/Volumes/SAMPlE 1
/Volumes/SAMPLE 2
```

and so on. To set up the array that contains all of these folders, I have

```
dirlist=(`ls -d /Volumes/*${prefix}*`);
```

When I run something like

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#dirlist[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "${dirlist[$i]}";
done
```

I get the folder names, but the spaces have created separate entries:

```
/Volumes/SAMPLE
/Volumes/SAMPLE
1
/Volumes/SAMPLE
2
/Volumes/SAMPLE
3
/Volumes/SAMPLE
4
/Volumes/SAMPLE
5
```

What do I need to do for the space not to separate the array and to be included as part of the directory?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why you shouldn't parse the results of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Also, see the section in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete mentioning "word splitting"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply [don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
dirlist=(/Volumes/*"${prefix}"*)
```

Example session:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch a 'foo bar' z
$ dirlist=(./*)
$ printf '%s\n' "${dirlist[@]}"
./a
./foo bar
./z
```

Comment: Might quote the expansion: `Volumes/*"$prefix"*`. Otherwise, spot on.

Comment: Also, to filter for directories, `/Volumes/*"$prefix"*/`. (Might use `mkdir` rather than `touch`, given the OP's intent).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Quoting isn't required here, is it?

Comment: If the prefix could contain spaces or otherwise characters in IFS, yes, it is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

don't need arrays for this

```
find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*${prefix}*"
```

however including spaces in filename and directory names is a terrible practice infected by Windows...

Comment: Whether spaces in names is or is not good practice seems rather an irrelevancy -- they're *possible*, so code that isn't robust against them has bugs.